# Stop ActionSheet from closing in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, popup

I have an ActionSheet in Ionic 3 and the last button of that is for Displaying more option. When the button is clicked 2 more buttons should be added on the ActionSheet. The problem is when I clicked any button, the ActionSheet is getting closed. I could not find out a way to stop it from closing. 
Is there any way to stop ActionSheet from closing?

```
  onMore(){
    let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Option 1',
          handler: () => {
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'More',
          handler: () => {
            this.showMore(actionSheet);
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    actionSheet.present();
  }


  private showMore(actionSheet){

    actionSheet.addButton({
      text: 'Option 2',
      handler: () => {
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simple.
Just add **`return false`** to your handler like below.

```
    onMore(){
    let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Option 1',
          handler: () => {
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'More',
          handler: () => {
            this.showMore(actionSheet);
            return false;
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    actionSheet.present();
  }
```

**[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-3eq5vx)**