# Ionic 4 ion-action-controller prevent auto close on button click

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to show the list of language available as an Action sheet. But as soon as the language button is pressed the action sheet closes automatically. Is there any possible way to prevent the auto close of ion-action-sheet controller on clicking the ActionsheetButton.

```
async showChangeLangAlert() {
    const actionSheet = await this.actionSheet.create(
      {
        header: this.translateText('Select language'),
        buttons: this.getLanguageInputTypes(),
        cssClass: 'confirmation-popup select-lang',
        backdropDismiss: true,
        mode: 'md'
      }
    );

    actionSheet.present();

    actionSheet.onWillDismiss().then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      event.preventDefault();
    });

    actionSheet.onDidDismiss().then(res => {
      this.langChoosen.next(this.selectedLanguage);
    });
  }

private getLanguageInputTypes(): ActionSheetButton[] {
    if (this.selectedLanguage === undefined) {
      this.selectedLanguage = 'en';
    }
    return [
      {
        text: this.translateText('English'),
        icon: (this.selectedLanguage.toLowerCase() === 'en') ? 'radio-button-on' : 'radio-button-off',
        cssClass: (this.selectedLanguage.toLowerCase() === 'en') ? 'active-option' : '',
        handler: () => {
          this.selectedLanguage = 'en';
        }
      },
      {
        text: this.translateText('German'),
        icon: (this.selectedLanguage.toLowerCase() === 'de') ? 'radio-button-on' : 'radio-button-off',
        cssClass: (this.selectedLanguage.toLowerCase() === 'de') ? 'active-option' : '',
        handler: () => {
          this.selectedLanguage = 'de';
        }
      },
      {
        text: this.translateText('Select'),
        icon: 'checkmark-circle',
        cssClass: (this.selectedLanguage.toLowerCase() === 'de') ? 'active-option' : '',
        handler: () => {
          this.setSelectedLanguage();
        }
      }
        ];
      }

private setSelectedLanguage() {
 // close the action-sheet here
}
```

I want to achieve the manual close of the action-sheet controller, but it closes automatically on clicking any action button. What I am missing or is there any workaround to show the alert window as an action sheet?

Comment: can you tell why you want to do this?

Comment: `backdropDismiss: false` pass this as attribute.

Comment: I achieved the desired using the alert controller and custom animation.

Comment: @Najamussaqib backdropDismiss is for closing the modal window by clicking outside it

Comment: if you're not looking for an answer any more then you can delete this question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56618975/stop-actionsheet-from-closing-in-ionic-3?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

the handler: ()=> returns to true after a button is clicked which dismisses the actionsheet. Returning false after the button is clicked in the handler() will keep the actionsheet in place.

```js
handler: ()=>{
// assign selected language
this.selectedLanguage = 'en';

// then return false

return false;

}
```

Answer (score -2):

backdropDismiss
Description 
If true, the action sheet will be dismissed when the backdrop is clicked.

Attribute   backdrop-dismiss
Type    boolean
Default true

```
backdropDismiss:false
```